# In ITIL, is an issue like an application suddenly won't open, an incident?

Tags: itil

Case 1:
Let's say that I have a recurring issue that causes an application to not launch. I know a workaround, I just try one more time but there is currently no fix to make it always open properly.

Case 2: I have a recurring issue that causes an application to not launch. I don't know a workaround or a fix.

Case 3 (obviously an incident): Your payment system service stops working for 3 minutes every now and again.

Case 3 is a classic incident that goes directly into Problem Management after.. 2 or 3 incidents I forget. How about case 1 and 2?

Comment: I thought that ITIL was the complement to project management; if it is a project, it isn't ITIL; if it is ITIL, it isn't a project.  Is this in scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1: Known Error

The issue needs to logged into Known Issues with Work Around, provide temporary fix and forwarded to Change Manager to be included in the next release cycle.

Case 2: As you said, its more than one instance of an incidence. It needs to be marked as an issue and needs to be fixed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

... and, to extend Tech's response ... make sure that the technical team which is ultimately responsible for making this **show-stopper** go away is aware of *both* of these cases.  If there appears to be "a consistent work-around," that is an extremely important clue.  Make sure that the teams are aware of *"every* ticket" that might possibly be relevant to the situation.